# how to check if input for barcode is valid using django?

Tags: python, django

I made an app to generate barcodes using python-barcode library (Python)(django framework)

and there's two fields

*1 - to let the user input the number that will used for generate the barcode*

*2 - options to let the user select which type of barcode he wants*

for now everything work fine it's generating the barcodes

but some of the barcodes have its specific types of inputs like 12 digits or 8 digits and so on

**so how to check the inputs if its valid for that type of barcode or not?, then show error messages if it's wrong, or succes message if it generated fine**

I know I can use messages form django itself but how I can implement it with checking function?

for views.py

```
from sre_constants import SUCCESS
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
import barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
import tempfile
from django.contrib import messages


def index(request):
   context = {'barcode_types':barcode.PROVIDED_BARCODES}
   return render(request, 'index.html',context)

def generate_barcode(request):
   inputs = request.POST['inputs']
   types = request.POST['types']
   barcode_class = barcode.get_barcode_class(types)
   file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
   code = barcode_class(inputs,writer=ImageWriter())
   file_path = code.save(file.name)
   response = HttpResponse(open(file_path,'rb').read(), headers={'Content-Type': 'image/png','Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="'+inputs+'.png"'})
return response
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django) inorder to validate user inputs

- You can set options on form inputs like `max_length`, `min_length`
- You can limit users to specific data types:

  - integer: `IntegerField`
  - short text: `CharField`
  - floating point numbers: `FloatField`
- You can make a field required: `required=True`
- You can give them some limited choices to choose from: `ChoiceField`
- [You can use additional validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/)

If I understood your question correctly, you need to validate the `inputs` based on `types`, so [according to the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other), you need to overwrite the `clean` function to perform multi-field validation

> The form subclass’s clean() method can perform validation that requires access to multiple form fields. This is where you might put in checks such as “if field A is supplied, field B must contain a valid email address”. This method can return a completely different dictionary if it wishes, which will be used as the cleaned_data.

here is an example:

```py
# forms.py

from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

BARCODE_TYPES =(
    # (value, display)
    ("Code39", "Code 39"),
    ("Code128", "Code 128"),
    ("PZN7", "PZN 7"),
    ("EuropeanArticleNumber13", "EAN-13"),
    ("EuropeanArticleNumber8", "EAN-8"),
    ("JapanArticleNumber", "JAN"),
    ("InternationalStandardBookNumber13", "ISBN-13"),
    ("InternationalStandardBookNumber10", "ISBN-10"),
    ("InternationalStandardSerialNumber", "ISSN"),
    ("UniversalProductCodeA", "UPC-A"),
    ("EuropeanArticleNumber14", "EAN-14"),
    ("Gs1_128", "Gs1-128"),
)
class BarcodeForm(forms.Form):
    # You can use max_lenth, min_length, ....
    inputs = forms.CharField(label='Bacode data', max_length=100, required=True)
    types = forms.ChoiceField(label='The Bracode type', choices=BARCODE_TYPES, required=True)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        inputs = cleaned_data.get("inputs")
        types = cleaned_data.get("types")

        if types == "Code39":
            # validate input for Code39
            # Raise error with the message you want on invalid input:
            raise ValidationError("Invalid input for Code 39 barcode type, you should ......")
        elif types == "Code128":
            # validate input for Code128
            # Raise error with the message you want on invalid input:
            raise ValidationError("Invalid input for Code 128 barcode type, you should ......")
        # .....
```

Then use this form in your views like this:
([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django))

```py
# views.py
from .forms import BarcodeForm

def generate_barcode(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = BarcodeForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
             # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
     # .....
```

Comment: thanks it was very helpful
I'm using barcode lib so it's already has everything to define which type and which digits it needs, there's anyway I can make if statement like that but using the lib values?

Comment: What do you mean **lib values**?
This is an example of Django forms.